# OpenAM webagent for JBoss AS 7.x

Tags: single-sign-on, jboss7.x, openam

Need a compatible openAM web agent for Jboss7. Or what can be done with existing version to make it compatible with JBoss AS 7?

jboss_v42_agent asks for the config path of Jboss while configuring and it does not accept any of the config paths in Jboss7.

Log of policy agent installation...

```
 ************************************************************************
    Welcome to the OpenAM Policy Agent for JBoss Server 4.x.

    ************************************************************************


    Enter the complete path to the directory which is used by JBoss Server to store
    its configuration Files. This directory uniquely identifies the JBoss
    Server instance that is secured by this Agent.
    [ ? : Help, ! : Exit ]
    Enter the JBoss Server Config Directory Path
    [C:\jboss-4.2.3\server\default\conf]: C:\jboss2\standalone\configuration


    ERROR: Invalid JBoss Server Config directory . Please try again.
    Invalid JBoss Server Config directory :
    C:\jboss2\standalone\configuration


    Enter the complete path to the directory which is used by JBoss Server to store
    its configuration Files. This directory uniquely identifies the JBoss
    Server instance that is secured by this Agent.
    [ ? : Help, ! : Exit ]
    Enter the JBoss Server Config Directory Path
    [C:\jboss-4.2.3\server\default\conf]:
```

Comment: Try to give some stripped down code that demonstrate your problem,  or at least that give proper taste of it.